# Checking conditions in C++

Tags: c++

I am working on a assignment that deals with boolean function on C++. It is asking for us to write a boolean function that asks the user for input and accepts it if it's either:

- X, x, O, o, L, l, I or i
- or a word starting with one of those letters

I am just confused on how to provide a condition that involves all those. I know how the start of it looks like and that it includes an if-else statement, but I am confused on what the condition should be.

My start:

```
bool isValidOption(char option, string & valOptions) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: If you're just using `valOptions` to validate their input why are you passing it by reference? You shouldn't be changing anything. Pass an array of strings containing the acceptable values and iterate through that array. If option == valOptions[i] return true. If it goes through the array and doesn't match, return false

Comment: "I am just confused on how to provide a condition that involves all those." You don't, you check them individually.

You should also show us anything else you have tried. [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::string` and its functions to do this easily.  You do not have to pass a reference to the `isValidOption` function. Here is a minimal example and you can expand on this.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::string;

bool isValidOption(char option, string valOptions) {
    return valOptions.find(option) != string::npos;    
}

int main() {    
    std::string valOptions = "XxOoLlIi";
    std::string inputString;
    cin >> inputString;
    string isValid = isValidOption(inputString[0], valOptions)? " is a Valid Option":" is an Invalid Option";
    cout << inputString << isValid;
}
```